# Visual Basic (based on VS2010 but working on VS2019) with GAX/GAT 2010 - Disabling Windows Forms elements depending of User roles ID

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms-designer

Currently I am in the middle of requested changes on a MIS software built on Visual Basic with GAT and GAX 2010.

The new task that I am having problem identifying is that under the Business modeling (Infrastructure, BusinessModule, etc.), I need to disable some GUI/ Windows Forms elements for a specific user with specific role and everything else untouched for all other users.

I know that I have to use the Security Controller but under the current applied coding of the software I am not getting a clear way to properly invoke  If/Else and have a .Controls.Remove(WindowsFormElement) applied within.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd be removing controls. Would it not be more appropriate to either disable or hide them? That way, you'd be setting a `Boolean` property - `Enabled` or `Visible` - and you wouldn't need an `If` statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what GAX/GAT 2010 is or whether it is specifically relevant to the issue but WinForms is not great for this kind of thing. If you were using WPF and MVVM then disabling or hiding controls would be done via the view model. If you haven't implemented the MVP pattern or the like in your WinForms app, as is probably the case, then things need to be a bit more manual. One option could be to set the `Tag` property relevant controls to a number representing the lowest role required to use that control. You can then set a `Boolean` by comparing that number to the current user's role.

Comment: Yeah, the first time I ever heard of both GAX and GAT is actually with this project, so my learning-o-the-go have been a bloody struggle and unfortunately is the backbone of the software and its structure is a must-have to apply even a seamless '.Enbaled=False' within a boolean or an If/Else.